# How to consume WCF service using .net 5

Tags: wcf, .net-5

I am trying add connected services to generate the proxy class and got this error.

[Creating WCF Service proxy class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGM2n.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use dotnet-svcutil tool. The Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) dotnet-svcutil tool is a .NET tool that retrieves metadata from a web service on a network location or from a WSDL file, and generates a WCF class containing client proxy methods that access the web service operations.

Similar to the Service Model Metadata - svcutil tool for .NET Framework projects, the dotnet-svcutil is a command-line tool for generating a web service reference compatible with .NET Core and .NET Standard projects.

For more information about "WCF dotnet-svcutil tool for .NET Core", you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x).

Comment: How-to call SOAP Service with ***CoreWCF***? in net5